# Is this the right way to use a repository pattern?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, repository-pattern

I'm using ASP 5, MVC 6, and Entity Framework 7 to create a small website (foreseeably less than 100 registered users and 10,000 monthly visitors). I'm a rookie programmer with under 1000 hours of combined experience and research.

I've got a lot of questions at the bottom, but in general I'd just like to be sure I understand the repository pattern and why it could be beneficial to me. Right now I'm only using it because I read 'it's good idea' from multiple sources, and because it seems to make sense for organizational purposes.

After I read about the Repository Pattern. I took some ideas from these sources:

[Microsoft](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application), [Code Guru](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_asp/mvc/using-the-repository-pattern-with-asp.net-mvc-and-entity-framework.htm), [DotNetCurry](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/aspnet-mvc/1155/aspnet-mvc-repository-pattern-perform-database-operations)

I created a generic interface IRepository:

```
interface IRepository<TEntity,in TPKey> where TEntity : class
{
    IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAll();
    TEntity Get(TPKey id);
    void Insert(TEntity ent);
    void Update(TEntity ent);
    void Delete(TEntity ent);
}
```

Then I created a specific Repository for one of my entities:

```
public class CollegeRepository : IRepository<Models.College, int>
{
    private ApplicationDbContext _context = null;

    public CollegeRepository()
    {
        _context = new ApplicationDbContext();
    }

    public CollegeRepository(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        this._context = context;
    }

    public College Get(int id)
    {
        return _context.Colleges.Where(c => c.CollegeID == id).FirstOrDefault();
    }

    public IEnumerable<College> GetAll()
    {
        return _context.Colleges.ToList();
    }

    public void Insert(College college)
    {
        _context.Colleges.Add(college);
    }

    public void Update(College college)
    {
        _context.Update(college);
    }

    public void Delete(College college)
    {
        _context.Colleges.Remove(college);
    }
```

Inside of my CollegesController I originally did something like this:

```
// POST: Schools/Edit/5
[HttpPost]
[Authorize]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public IActionResult Edit(College school, IFormFile logo)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (logo != null)
        {
            byte[] imgBytes = new byte[logo.Length];
            logo.OpenReadStream().Read(imgBytes, 0, (int)logo.Length);
            school.Logo = imgBytes;
            _context.Update(school);
        }
        else
        {
            // Mark the logo as unmodified so the data is not lost.
            _context.Update(school).Property(s => s.Logo).IsModified = false;
        }               
        _context.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(school);
}
```

Then changed to this:

```
// POST: Schools/Edit/5
[HttpPost]
[Authorize]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public IActionResult Edit(College school, IFormFile logo)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        collegeRepo.Update(school, logo);                
        _context.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(school);
}
```

And modified the specific repository to add an Update overload:

```
public class CollegeRepository : IRepository<Models.College, int>
{
    public void Update(College college)
    {
        _context.Update(college);
    }

    public void Update(College college, IFormFile logo)
    {
        if (logo != null)
        {
            byte[] imgBytes = new byte[logo.Length];
            logo.OpenReadStream().Read(imgBytes, 0, (int)logo.Length);
            college.Logo = imgBytes;
            _context.Update(college);
        }
        else
        {
            // Mark the logo as unmodified so the data is not lost.
            _context.Update(college).Property(s => s.Logo).IsModified = false;
        }

    }
}
```

It seems I have successfully separated my logic from my controller. Is this the idea behind the repository pattern? Have I used it successfully in this example? To what degree am I unsuccessful? 
I was reading, after I did all this, that the repository pattern is not all that useful for projects which will only use (and may only ever use) 1 data source (like mine), but that there should always be some sort of Unit of Work class to keep logic out of controllers (I vaguely understand what it means to have a unit of work, but answers that touch on this would be appreciated as well).
I've also read that the repository pattern is helpful for reducing duplicate code. I can't see far enough ahead, with my inexperienced eyes, to think that I might use any of my controller code again. What are some common MVC scenarios where you've seen (could see) code duplication occur without the repository pattern?

Comment: I suggest you to check this also https://genericunitofworkandrepositories.codeplex.com/ nice implementation of Repository and UnitOfWork

Comment: I have been down this road too until I realised that EF  is essentially this pattern already. I was doing this to more easily decouple and test my code through the creation of fakes etc. I found there was no benefit at the scale I was programming for. IMO, based on my limited understanding of your problem, I would just create a service layer that abstracts the DBContext calls / work out of your controllers for the sake of neatness- then you can easily test this service layer, and test your controllers with MOQ or some other mocking tool. Good luck- I'm looking forward to seeing the discussion.

Comment: The Entity Framework `DbContext` is _already_ a repository. I'm not convinced you need to abstract it away further. If you have some slightly more complex update scenarios and you don't want to somply add the method to the context itself, you could write the logic in an extension method and access the same logic from multiple sources in that way.